# Find the biggest number in multidimensional nested arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a question related to multidimensional arrays in php. I would like to find the biggest number in a random multidimensional array by looping through all the arrays and the nested arrays.

I tried to search a lot but I couldn't find a solution for more than 2 level deep nested arrays (for example, the max number could be in the 3rd level array).

For example, for this array `[40, [194, [23, 234, 500], 57], 93, 39, [10, 333, 49]]`, the right answer should be 500, with index of array[1][1][2], but how to get the number by looping to multiple level deep arrays and find the max number from all those arrays? I think the loop shouldn't be only for this array, but in general to any multidimensional array, but if a general solution doesn't exist, I'd like to know some explanation about this particular array.

Thanks.

Comment: https://snipplr.com/view/10200/recursively-traverse-a-multidimensional-array/

Comment: @KourkenK Andreas is completely correct in nominating the Exact Duplicate and I support it.  I did find that the earlier duplicate page did not offer a solution using `array_walk_recursive()` so I have added a new solution that demonstrates and explains the very clean/direct/appropriate technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the follow idea: if element is array them call the function recursively.

This way you can solve this for any depth of nested arrays.
Pesado code:

```
function maxInMultiDim($array) {
    $max = 0; //assume all num are positive else assign MIN_INT
    foreach($array as $elem) {
        $temp = $elem;
        if (is_array($elem))
            $elem = maxInMultiDim($elem);
        $max = ($max < $elem ) ? $elem : $max;
    }
    return $max;
}
```

Sorry for any syntax mistake...

Answer (score 0):

If you know how deep the array goes, you can use multiple loops, 1 for each depth. For example, with your array which has up to 3 depths, you could do:

```
$a = [40, [194, [23, 234, 500], 57], 93, 39, [10, 333, 49]];
$max = 0;
foreach ($a as $b) {
    if (is_array($b)) {
        foreach ($b as $c) {
            if (is_array($c)) {
                foreach ($c as $d) {
                    $max = $d > $max ? $d : $max;
                }
            } else {
                $max = $c > $max ? $c : $max;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $max = $b > $max ? $b : $max;
    }
}
return $max;
```